# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre enum y sealed en Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Cual es la diferencia entre `enum` (Enum Classes) y `sealed` (Clases selladas). Y cuando es recomendable utilizarlos.

```
enum class Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST
}

sealed class Direction {
    class NORTH
    class SOUTH
    class WEST
    class EAST
}
```

Comment: este es un artículo que explica lo que son las clases selladas: https://arturogutierrez.com/blog/creando-enumerados-con-datos-asociados-en-kotlin/

Comment: vienen a ser una extensión de las enumeraciones al permitir que cada valor de la enumeración pueda ser un objeto o clase distintos entre ellos, con las posibles ventajas que ofrece esto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Las Sealed Classes (Clases selladas)](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) se utilizan para representar jerarquías de clases restringidas, cuando un valor puede tener uno de los tipos de un conjunto limitado, pero no puede tener ningún otro tipo.

**[Las Sealed Classes](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) son, en cierto sentido, una extensión de las [clases enum](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html)**: el conjunto de valores para un tipo enum también está restringido, pero cada constante enum existe solo como una sola instancia, mientras que una subclase de una clase sellada puede tener múltiples instancias que pueden contener estado.

---

- **En una enumeración, solo se puede tener un objeto por cada tipo.**
- **En una clase sellada se pueden tener varios objetos de la misma clase.**

Te presento estos ejemplo para que veas la diferencia, en cuando a tu pregunta ¿cuando es recomendable utilizarlos?

en realidad las [Sealed Classes (Clases selladas)](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) se podría decir que es un "Enum con esteroides".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Enum](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html):

```
enum class Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST
}
```

[Sealed Class](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html):  Una clase con un numero especifico de subclases

```
sealed class Direction{
    class North(val value: Int) : Direction()
    class South(val value: Int) : Direction()
    class West(val value: Int) : Direction()
    class East(val value: Int) : Direction()

}

fun execute(direction: Direction)= when (direction) {
    is Direction.North -> direction.value + 0
    is Direction.East ->  direction.value + 90
    is Direction.South ->  direction.value + 180
    is Direction.West ->  direction.value + 270
}
```